# Why is charge conjugation $\hat C | \alpha \psi \rangle = C_\alpha |\alpha\psi \rangle$?

Tags: symmetry, charge-conjugation

Charge conjugation replaces all particles by antiparticles in the same state, so that momenta, positions, etc are unchanged. It can be represented by 
$$\hat C | \alpha \psi \rangle = C_\alpha |\alpha\psi \rangle =  |\bar \alpha  \psi \rangle$$

where $| \alpha \psi \rangle$ is the state of a particle $\alpha$ and $C_\alpha$ is a phase factor and $|\bar \alpha  \psi \rangle$ is the stater of the antiparticle.

Why is it that the state of an antiparticle has the same form as a particle with the same position, momemtum etc? Why can't the state of the antiparticle be a general $|\phi \rangle$ where $|\phi \rangle \ne C_\alpha |\alpha\psi \rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any transformation $C$ that deserves to be called charge conjugation, any other transformation obtained by composing $C$ with a proper Lorentz transformation is equally deserving of the name charge conjugation, and likewise for any transformation obtained by composing $C$ with some other internal symmetry. It's a matter of convention which one we single out to call "the" charge conjugation transformation.